# OpenERP (view) - change with space between label and field?

Tags: css, xml, view, label, odoo

How can I change width space between label and its field? Now it has fixed space between label and its field for example like this:

```
label1        field1
label2        field2
label3        field3
```

If I my labels would be of different size then view would look like this..:

```
label1                    field1
longer_label2             field2
even_longer_label3        field3
```

Didn't find any way to reduce spacing between label and field. It looks that if space is missing, OpenERP tries to reduce field width first, but not the space between label and field.
To get even better picture what I'm talking about, look at this image:

[image]

You can see that space between label ('Dispečerinė') and actual field is fixed, but instead it reduced field width, where now you can't really see much and can't choose value properly (it reduced like this, because there were more fields on same line than it could put). So how could I adjust that spacing, so I could put more fields on same line and not mess it like in an image?

P.S. Maybe it is possible to change position of labels, so they would appear above field and would not occupy same line?

EDIT:
**Example code**

```
<group> 
    <group>
        <group>
            <field name="partner_dispatch_id"/>
            <field name="company_amb_id"/>
            <field name="call_id"/>
            <field name="patient_numb"/>
        </group>
        <group>
            <field name="dispatcher_numb"/>
            <field name="team_crew_id"/>
            <field name="life_support"/>
            <field name="adv_life_support"/>
        </group>
        </group>
    <group>
</group>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can revert back by modifying this file

> "addons/web/static/src/css/base.css"

```
.openerp .oe_form td.oe_form_group_cell_label label 
{
    line-height: 18px;
    display: block;
    min-width: 140px; /* Remove this line */
 }
```